# UITableView not showing left-side multiple selection circles on edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get the standard multiple selection behavior for UITableView as in the system Mail.app and Messages.app when edit is pressed in the inboxes. I am setting `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to YES, and am calling `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]` when my edit button is pressed. However, everything remains still and the open circles do not emerge from the left side of the cell as I want them to. I am not setting any of the UITableViewCells' `accessoryType` or calling `setEditing` on any of them as it is.

Is there anything I am missing, or something further that I have to do? To be clear, I am looking for the left-side multiple selection functionality, not the floating checkmarks that might appear on the right side of the cell. Thanks

**Edit**: I just realized that I should specify that I am not using a table view within a UITableViewController, but rather one that is placed within a UIViewController. Am I not able to get this functionality without using a UITableViewController?

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too and u can accept it too

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

It turns out that I was not properly returning YES for the data source method canEditRowAtIndexPath. So it looks like multiple selection is different (right side checkmarks vs left side circle selection checkmarks) depending on whether the table view knows it can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    if (editing) {
        addButton.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        addButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *controller = (SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (indexPath.row == [controller countOfList]-1) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *controller = (SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [controller removeObjectFromListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although it wasn't exactly the answer, your code with some of the data source methods helped me stumble upon the solution. Cheers!

Comment: you are welcome any way can you post your code. I want to study the code you are implementing